# Make category archives page in menu non-clickable

Tags: categories, archives

I have a website with 2 categories in the menu. The first one is "Blog", which I would like to keep when you click on it. The second one is "Veel bezocht" and there are a few posts linked to this category.

Currenlty the "Veel bezocht" is clickable and you land on this page: http://www.10-kilo-afvallen.nl/category/veel-bezocht/. I would like "Veel bezocht" to be non-clickable when visitors hoover on this item, so the visitors can only click on the posts related to this category.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but it depends a bit on your theme. On my local environment with Twenty Seventeen enabled it did work.

1. Add a new "custom link" entry to the menu. Fill in anything for the URL and "Veel bezocht" as the link text
2. with the custom link in the "menu structure", simply remove the URL and save the menu